# Working with nest device access console for masters project

Tags: nest-device-access

we are a group of students trying to develop an app that can add smart devices such as Nest and LIFX devices for a masters project. We have been successfully able to integrate our personal nest device into the app using device access sandbox.

Do we need to apply for commercial development if we want the app to be able to multiple user's Nest devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work but you could try adding the email associated with the sandbox to the home of the other users.  That is, give that email access in Google Home or the Nest app.